# Pebble SDK manifest.json not found

Tags: android, pebble-sdk

Having some issues building and installing one of the Pebble sample apps using Android.

I'm trying to install the [Tricorder](https://github.com/pebble-examples/tricorder) example, so I ran

```
pebble build
```

which succeeded; but when I run

```
pebble install --phone 129.161.93.98
```

to install via the phone, I get an `Unfortunately, Pebble has stopped.` error on Android.

The ADB log shows this:

```
11-14 17:44:50.550  31705-31770/? E/PebbleApplication﹕ [SyncBootConfig] No message provided!
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
            at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.get(SimpleFuture.java:84)
            at com.getpebble.android.http.HttpRequestUtil.fetchBootConfig(HttpRequestUtil.java:45)
            at com.getpebble.android.config.SyncBootConfig.syncBootConfig(SyncBootConfig.java:71)
            at com.getpebble.android.config.SyncBootConfig$BootConfigSyncTask.doInBackground(SyncBootConfig.java:44)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.core.async.PblAsyncTask.doInBackground(PblAsyncTask.java:49)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.core.async.PblAsyncTask.doInBackground(PblAsyncTask.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 17:44:52.864  31705-31705/? E/PebbleApplication﹕ [MyPebbleFragment] handleArguments: sideLoadingUri was null
11-14 17:44:52.883  31705-31705/? E/PebbleApplication﹕ [MainActivity] previousFragment was null
11-14 17:44:53.834  31729-31760/? E/PebbleApplication﹕ [PebbleBundle] Failed to parse manifest.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find entry for manifest.json
            at com.getpebble.android.common.framework.install.PebbleBundle.getInputStreamForComponent(PebbleBundle.java:61)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.framework.install.PebbleBundle.parseManifest(PebbleBundle.java:71)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.framework.install.app.AppBundle.<init>(AppBundle.java:72)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.install.app.AppBundleManager.getBundleFromFile(AppBundleManager.java:42)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.install.app.AppBundleManager.getBundleFromFile(AppBundleManager.java:23)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.install.PebbleBundleManager.fetchBundleFromUri(PebbleBundleManager.java:87)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.endpoint.InstallAppEndpoint.addAppSync(InstallAppEndpoint.java:247)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.endpoint.InstallAppEndpoint$3.doInBackground(InstallAppEndpoint.java:221)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.core.async.PblAsyncTask.doInBackground(PblAsyncTask.java:49)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.core.async.PblAsyncTask.doInBackground(PblAsyncTask.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 17:44:53.836  31729-31760/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.getpebble.android:framework, PID: 31729
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'Manifest' cannot be null!
            at com.getpebble.android.common.framework.install.app.AppBundle.<init>(AppBundle.java:74)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.install.app.AppBundleManager.getBundleFromFile(AppBundleManager.java:42)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.install.app.AppBundleManager.getBundleFromFile(AppBundleManager.java:23)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.install.PebbleBundleManager.fetchBundleFromUri(PebbleBundleManager.java:87)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.endpoint.InstallAppEndpoint.addAppSync(InstallAppEndpoint.java:247)
            at com.getpebble.android.framework.endpoint.InstallAppEndpoint$3.doInBackground(InstallAppEndpoint.java:221)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.core.async.PblAsyncTask.doInBackground(PblAsyncTask.java:49)
            at com.getpebble.android.common.core.async.PblAsyncTask.doInBackground(PblAsyncTask.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-14 17:45:01.174  31729-31800/? E/PebbleApplication﹕ [PblInboundPingMessage] Unexpected format.  Not ping?
```

If I try to install the Pebble app directly via BlueTooth serial with

```
pebble install --serial /dev/tty.Pebble0DF7-SerialPortSe
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find Manifest.json; are you sure this is a PebbleBundle
```

Note: This is on the Pebble steel with Android 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by creating a new Pebble project using this command from the [guides](https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/publishing-tools/pebble-tool/)

```
pebble new-project [--simple] [--javascript] [--worker] NAME
```

Still not sure what caused it in the example project, but creating a new one and copying files over seemed to produce the desired effect.